# Why is an object's method not available for another object?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function Vector(i, j, k){
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    this.k = k;
};

Vector.prototype = {
    addition: function(vec){
        return new Vector(vec.i+this.i, vec.j+this.j, vec.k+this.k);
    },
    magnitude: function(){
        return Math.sqrt(this.i*this.i + this.j*this.j + this.k*this.k);
    },
};

function Orbit(rp, ra, ecc){
    this.rp = new Vector(rp, 0, 0);
    this.ra = new Vector(ra, 0, 0);
    this.a = this.rp.addition(this.ra).magnitude(); //The error is in this line
};

var orbit = new Orbit(6563, 42165);
```

So what I'm trying to do here is create `Vector` objects for `rp`, `ra` in the `Orbit` object. `a` is supposed to utilize the prototype methods of the vectors `rp` and `ra`, but when I run the script, the prototype methods of `rp` are not available and I get an error saying:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.rp.addition(this.ra)')
```

I hope this isn't a dumb mistake that I'm missing somewhere, because this has been giving me some trouble for a while. This is my first time ever using prototypes in JS, so I don't see what I'm doing wrong here. I just need to know why `this.rp` does not have the `Vector` methods and what I could do to fix my code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't where you think it is.

`this.a` is built as :

```
this.a = this.rp.addition(this.ra).magnitude();
```

which means it's a number, so you can't take `this.a.magnitude()`

I suppose `this.a` wasn't supposed to be the magnitude (or you're changed your mind). A fix would be to change it's construction to

```
this.a = this.rp.addition(this.ra);
```

Comment: `this.a` is supposed to be a number and the operations I'm doing to get it should work. `this.rp.addition(this.ra)` just does vector addition to add them together and then I'm finding the magnitude of that. In the console, I'm able to do `orbit.a = orbit.rp.addition(orbit.ra).magnitude()`, so I don't see why the above doesn't work.

Comment: @EvanA The problem isn't in computing `this.rp.addition(this.ra).magnitude()`, but in taking the magnitude after, that is `this.rp.addition(this.ra).magnitude().magnitude()`